# Restrict search and replace?

Tags: jquery, replace

I have this function using replace(), it finds the value '0 €' and replaces with 'no price'. It works fine but the problem is tha it match 
this 
'0 €'
but also this
'10 €'.

I need it only to match '0 €' **but not '10 €'.**

js:

```
$('.field-name').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('0 €', 'no price')); 
});
```

Comment: Is that your whole text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this :

```
$(this).text(text.replace(/(^|\D)0\s*€/g, 'no price'));
```

This would replace "0 $" but only at the start of the string or after something that is not a digit.